# Testing Error messages to be shown for user

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to write a test to assert that my login page displays an error when the user enters an incorrect username or password.

```
    @if ($errors->any())
      <p>Looks like you’ve entered the wrong username or password. 
        <a href="{{route('password.request')}}">
           Click here</a> to reset your  password“ </p></div>
    @endif
```

The functionality is working fine and I can see the errors on page, but for some reason, I can't get my test to pass.

->assertSessionHasErrors() is working fine, while ->assertSeeText() is not detecting the error messages in text.
`

```
public function userSeesErrorMessage() {
  $user = factory('App\User')->create([
        'password' => bcrypt($password = 'test'),
    ]);
    $response = $this->followingRedirects()
    ->post('/login', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => 'incorrectPassword'
    ]);
    $response->assertSeeText('Looks like you’ve entered the wrong username or password. Click here to reset your password');
}`
```

The response seem to contain the whole document's HTML, except for the part about the errors.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a few reasons why this does does not work. Easiest thing you could do is to set a header for a referer. This way the validation will know where to redirect you back, because currently you're not submitting a form and the redirect is sending you to a page where you might not display the errors:

```
$response = $this->followingRedirects()
    ->post(
        '/login', 
        [
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'incorrectPassword'
        ], 
        ['referer' => '/login']
    );
```

Another issue might be that the session errors are lost within the redirects, where you can try following the redirect separately:

```
$r = $this->post('/login', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => 'incorrectPassword'
    ]);

$r->assertStatus(302);
$r->assertSessionHasErrors('email');

$r = $this->followRedirects($r);

$r->assertSeeText('Looks like you’ve entered the wrong username or password. Click here to reset your password');
```